# Django: setting template_name doesn't work in Class-based View

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a `ProductListView`:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products/product_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
```

I tried to create another `ListView` listing `Product`:

```
class VoteView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'recommendation/rec_product_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
```

But when I tried to access `VoteView` in a browser, it occurs errors : it rendered `product_list.html`, not `rec_product_list.html`.

So I debugged it and fount out that `get_template_names()` returns,
`['recommendation/rec_product_list.html', 'products/product_list.html']`.

I could fix this by inserting this code:

```
def get_template_names(self):
    return ['recommendation/rec_product_list.html']
```

But wonder whether there is better way than this one..

Thanks

Comment: by default your `ListView` will automatically assign `products/product_list.html` if the app name is `product`.  Is the error `TemplateDoesNotExist` ?

Comment: What version of Django do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was with app name in my template_name configuration. I used project name instead of app name and template was looked up in project template folder. Template was not found and silently ListView took default template from App folder. I found this only thanks to above get_template_names method as it raised error rather than silently failing and taking default :).